# Redeclare .net classes in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython, monkeypatching

Can anyone tell me if its possible to redeclare a C# class in IronPython? If I have a C# class, would I be able to monkey-patch it from IronPython?

Comment: As a clarification, I want to know how to monkey-patch c# classes from IronPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot monkey patch from IronPython.  IronPython treats all .NET classes just like CPython treats built-in types: they cannot be monkey patched.  IronRuby on the other hand does support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey-patch from IronPython, but IPy is the only environment that will respect your changes; i.e. if you tried to mock out File.Create from IronPython, this would work fine for any IPy code, but if you called a C# method which called File.Create, it would get the real one, not the mock.

Comment: How do you do this? When I try it on my own classes I get this message:
AttributeError: attribute 'methodName' of 'className' object is read-only

Answer (score -1):

Why would you redeclare it?  Wouldn't it make more sense to [subclass it](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dynamically_compiling.shtml) or just make a totally new class?

EDIT: Give your clarification, I think what you actually need is a proper inversion of control (IOC) framework, such as [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html).  Basically, you have a database interface, then configure the IOC framework to inject a real database for production, and  mock database for testing.

Comment: I want to redeclare the constructor because the class tries to access the database in the constructor and that makes it difficult to unit test. By redeclaring the constructor I can point the class to a mock database and unit test it without hitting the actual database. Thanks for responding.